# Crontab: cut line to many lines?

Tags: line, cron

**Hard-to-read-line**

```
@daily export sunshine="~/logs/Sunshine-`date '+\%F'`" && export sunshineUrl="http://www.sunshine.net/main/search_results.asp?currency_id=1&min_price=&max_price=50000&country_id=241&region_id=&Submit=Search" && mkdir -p $sunshine && cd $sunshine && wget --mirror -l 1 $sunshineUrl
```

**Which mark do I need to have it on many lines?**

```
@daily   <SOME MARK HERE>
export sunshine="~/logs/Sunshine-`date '+\%F'`" &&  <SOME MARK HERE>
export sunshineUrl="http://www.sunshine.net/main/search_results.asp?currency_id=1&min_price=&max_price=50000&country_id=241&region_id=&Submit=Search" && <SOME MARK HERE>
mkdir -p $sunshine && <SOME MARK HERE>
cd $sunshine && wget --mirror -l 1 $sunshineUrl
```

No success by appending \, //, \n or /n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be easier to take all the above and create a shell script from it ? It'll be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Much, much, much more maintainable!

Comment: Thank you, I will buy your tip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do it with a semicolon ; but I agree with Brian that you need to take the above and put it in a script and run from cron.

Comment: @daily ;
echo "hello" && ;
echo "haeus atestaoe usn"   <-- not working with enters

Comment: Don't add a semicolon after the &&. Semicolons separate commands and will run the command on the right regardless of exit status of left hand command. While && will only run right hand command only if command on left is successful. (|| only runs right if left fails.)

Comment: I meant to take out the && and put a semicolon... two seperate export statements

export sunshine="~/logs/Sunshine-`date '+\%F'`"; export sunshineUrl="http://www.sunshine.net/main/search_results.asp?currency_id=1&min_price=&max_price=50000&country_id=241&region_id=&Submit=Search"; etc...